# How to convert a data.frame to a matrix?

Tags: r, database

I have a data frame like this: three columns, species, the compounds emitted by the species, and `1` in `status` means the compound present in the species. And in this format, there is no `0`, which will indicate "absent".

[image]

Now, I want convert the data frame to a matrix like this: first column with `species`, the rest of the columns with `compounds`, and use `1` and `0` indicate "present" and "absent", respectively.

[image]

Is there a R code can do this? As you can see, there are so many rows in the original data frame. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `dcast`

```
library(reshape2)
dcast(data, species ~compounda, value.var = 'status', fill = 0)
```

If we need a `matrix` use change `dcast` to `acast`